# Videos are there in array how to play the that videos. iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, video

Videos are there in array. I want to play that videos.

Means Videos are there in server. And videos are come in an array. I stored that array i a dictionary from the dictionary how to play videos

is the below code is right or wrong if its wrong please tell me correct one

```
enter code here NSMutableDictionary *dict;


dict =[Videoarray objectAtIndex:0];
NSURL *Movie = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[dict valueForKey:@"url"]];
MPMoviePlayerController *theMovie = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:Movie];
theMovie.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill;
[theMovie play];
MPMoviePlayerController *movie = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:Movie];
movie.view.frame = CGRectMake(5,5,310, 165);
movie.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight |
UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | 
UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
[scroll addSubview:movie.view];
[movie play];
```

Comment: Did you try the code? What isn't working?

Comment: Only one video is coming but in array so may videos is there how to retrieve all videos. in iphone

Comment: You want them to play consecutively, right?

Comment: Yes, But videos are listed in table, and Video must play in the same view when click on the video list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very rough code to play an array of videos consecutively:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad { 
     [self setUpPlayer];
}

-(void)setUpPlayer {
   if(i <= [videoArray count]) {
        player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[videoArray objectAtIndex:i]];
        i++; //use a static integer outside these functions as an index
        [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(movieFinishedCallback:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:player];
        [player play];
    }
}


- (void) movieFinishedCallback:(NSNotification*) aNotification {
    player = [aNotification object];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:player];    
    [self setUpPlayer];
 }
```